# Uploading multiple C# solution to plesk panel

Tags: c#, plesk, shared-hosting, plesk-onyx

I'm setting a new server where I have two C# projects solutions (Web API). I have uploaded one of it to the Plesk panel under the httpdocs folder and that is working fine (e.g mysite.com/project1/getCustomerDate). Now I want to upload my second API C# solution under some subfolder of httpdocs and want to access it like mysite.com/project2/MakeBooking.

How I can upload the second C# solution to Plesk panel?

I have created one subfolder and tried to publish the Solution to that subfolder from the visual studio and it gets uploaded but I am not able to access my API, It shows an error like "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed or is temporarily unavailable."  while accessing it in postman.

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple C# Web application can be hosted in the Plesk panel, one is required to make the necessary changes into the RouteConfig.cs and WebApiConfig.cs (if it is there).
**Note: This need to be done in each hosted solutions**

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "APIofSolution1",
            routeTemplate: "apitype1/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "APIofSolution2",
            routeTemplate: "<folderName>/apitype2/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```